# Can a Player register in multiple clubs? or more than one?

Tags: football, fifa, transfer

According to FIFA rules, can professional players register in more than one club at the same time? or at one season?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pro players can not be registered with more than one club at the same time. Only amateurs can in some regions.

Transfers between clubs are possible during the season, but limited to [registration periods](https://resources.fifa.com/image/upload/regulations-on-the-status-and-transfer-of-players-august-2020.pdf?cloudid=bbsxdddzsakplwzf0psu). These are more commonly known as transfer windows and there are usually two per season. The exact times are different for each country and depend on the schedule of the domestic competitions, but usually there is a longer summer period and a short winter period.

Comment: But according to Art 5. Of FIFA players status and transfer Reg. “Players may be registered with a maximum of three clubs during one season. During this period, the player is only eligible to play official matches for two clubs”.

Comment: @legalresearcher three clubs *per season*, but not at the same time. You start with one club into the season, transfer to another one during period 1 and transfer again during period 2 = three clubs. This happens quite often when clubs sign players late into period 1 and put them on loan in period 2 when they're not good enough for the team yet.